# Windows 7 not recognizing USB drivers for Toshiba Satellite L655-S5098

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I have a Toshiba Satellite L655-S5098 Windows 7. Windows is not recognizing the USB.

I did some research, and they say you should uninstall the USB Drivers and reinstall them. There are like 10 different driver devices for USB at the Toshiba support site. Should I individually uninstall all of the USB device drivers and than work from there?

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any usb drivers on the [download](http://www.csd.toshiba.com/cgi-bin/tais/support/jsp/modelContent.jsp?ct=DL&os=&category=&moid=2759985&rpn=PSK2CU&modelFilter=&selCategory=2756709&selFamily=1073768663) page, which would indicate that the USB drivers are already present within Windows.

If you have an issue with USB, please rewrite your question with the details of the issue so help can be provided.